# Printing all properties set via Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

I’d like to print the consolidated list of properties set in our application on startup. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring: access all Environment properties as a Map or Properties object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506471/spring-access-all-environment-properties-as-a-map-or-properties-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom [`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) that overrides the `resolve...` methods and logs the `placeholder` name. You may also need/want to override the `convert...` methods, but `resolve...` should handle it.

Answer (score 5):

This is my implementation:

```
public class CustomPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer implements InitializingBean{

    public void afterPropertiesSet(){
        try{
            Properties loadedProperties = this.mergeProperties();
            for(Entry<Object, Object> singleProperty : loadedProperties.entrySet()){
                logger.info("LoadedProperty: "+singleProperty.getKey()+"="+singleProperty.getValue());
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: base class doesn't have the method

Comment: Weakness of your solution - if any property has error - you'll never see all these properties in log file since afterPropertiesSet() won't be invoked.

Comment: Does not work for me, no properties in the list at all.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a concrete example of printing all properties :

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment;

public class PropertiesLoaderConfigurer
    extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {

    private static final String ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTIES = "environmentProperties";

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(
        final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
        throws BeansException {

        super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);

        final StandardServletEnvironment propertySources =
            (StandardServletEnvironment) super.getAppliedPropertySources().get(ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTIES).getSource();

        propertySources.getPropertySources().forEach(propertySource -> {
            if (propertySource.getSource() instanceof Map) {
                // it will print systemProperties, systemEnvironment, application.properties and other overrides of
                // application.properties
                System.out.println("#######" + propertySource.getName() + "#######");

                final Map<String, String> properties = mapValueAsString((Map<String, Object>) propertySource.getSource());
                System.out.println(properties);
            }
        });
    }

    private Map<String, String> mapValueAsString(
        final Map<String, Object> map) {

        return map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> toString(entry.getValue())));
    }

    private String toString(
        final Object object) {

        return Optional.ofNullable(object).map(value -> value.toString()).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Weakness of this solution is that it prints all sources property mapping individually possibly duplicated values for overrided keys instead of printing only the result values for all properties .