# View all Spring Configuration files loaded so far

Tags: java, spring

My project consists of several `@Configuration` annotated bean configuration classes.

How can I print out all the configuration classes that have been loaded?

I have read these questions but they don't seem to apply to my use case:

- [Log all loaded configuration in spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060907/log-all-loaded-configuration-in-spring-boot-application)
- [Printing all properties set via Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298344/printing-all-properties-set-via-spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ApplicationContext#getBeansWithAnnotation`. It will not only take classes with `@Configuration` annotation but also classes annotated with annotations meta-annotated with `@Configuration`, like `@SpringBootApplication`:

```java
@Bean
ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
  return args -> {
    applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Configuration.class)
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getClass().getPackage().getName().startsWith("com.your.package"))
      .forEach(entry -> {
      System.out.println("name: " + entry.getKey() + ", bean: " + entry.getValue());
    });
  };
}
```